# Synchronize scrolling on two TextBoxes

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two TextBoxes and a ScrollBar. With the scrollbar I want to scroll both TextBoxes. The maximum value of the scrollbar is the maximum of the maximum values of the two textbox scrollbars.

My problem is that if the text inside a TextBox is not bigger than the textbox itself, the text won't scroll. How can I force the text to be scrollable?

Here is my code:

```
<Window x:Class="HorizontalScrollViewerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
    Loaded="MainWindow_OnLoaded">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
             x:Name="UpperTextBox"
             Text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
             x:Name="LowerTextBox"
             Text="abc"
             HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
    <ScrollBar Grid.Row="2"
               x:Name="ScrollBar"
               Orientation="Horizontal"
               Value="{Binding ScrollValue, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
using System;
using System.Windows;

namespace HorizontalScrollViewerTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ScrollValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ScrollValue", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(int), ScrollValueChanged));

        private static void ScrollValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            (d as MainWindow).UpperTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((int)e.NewValue);
            (d as MainWindow).LowerTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((int)e.NewValue);
        }

        public int ScrollValue
        {
            get => (int) GetValue(ScrollValueProperty);
            set => SetValue(ScrollValueProperty, value);
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MainWindow_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var maxExtent = Math.Max(UpperTextBox.ExtentWidth, LowerTextBox.ExtentWidth);
            ScrollBar.Maximum = Math.Max(ScrollBar.ActualWidth, maxExtent) - ScrollBar.ActualWidth;
            ScrollBar.ViewportSize = ScrollBar.ActualWidth;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the text isn't large enough to enable scrolling, what do you expect to happen when you "force" it to scroll? Have you tried appending lines until the 2 texts are the same length?

Comment: @JeffR.: I want both text segments to move synchronously. To make it clear, both texts should only be scrollable if at least one text segment is scrollable. I haven't tried appending spaces at the end of the lines because the visual behavior should be independant of the specific content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just wrap these two TextBoxes in a ScrollViewer?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="true" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
     x:Name="UpperTextBox"
     Text="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
     x:Name="LowerTextBox"
     Text="abc"/>
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

If you cannot wrap the `TextBoxes` you can apply a `Margin` to them instead of using `ScrollToHorizontalOffset`:

```
    private static void ScrollValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        (d as MainWindow).UpperTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(-1 * (int)e.NewValue, 0, 0, 0);
        (d as MainWindow).LowerTextBox.Margin = new Thickness(-1 * (int)e.NewValue, 0, 0, 0);
        //(d as MainWindow).UpperTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((int)e.NewValue * 100);
        //(d as MainWindow).LowerTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset((int)e.NewValue * 100);
    }
```

You should also compute the `ScrollBar.Maximum` and the `ScrollBar.ViewportSize` each time one of the component is resized:

```
<ScrollBar Grid.Row="2" SizeChanged="MainWindow_OnLoaded" [...]/>
```

Comment: I can't put a scrollviewer around it, because I actually have two columns in the grid and I don't want the first column to scroll.

Comment: It's not about column, you can have multiple Grid. The problem is whether or not your two TextBoxes can be grouped. See my edit.

Comment: They can't be grouped, they are actually in a DataGrid. I just put them in a Grid for an easy example.

Comment: I added a solution. It's not very "clean", but you don't need much changes to your code.

Comment: That's a nice idea with the margin. It's a bit too "hacky" for my case, but I'll accept it nonetheless.